# Opening a text file in Python

Tags: python, file, text, file-io

I am having trouble reading a text file to a list, what I have at the moment is:

```
lines = open ('dracula.txt', 'r'). readlines ()
```

where dracula.txt is the text file in the same directory as the program, however upon running the program Python comes up with:

```
No such file or directory: 'dracula.txt'
```

I have no idea why it will not find the text file and read it to a list called lines, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you are launching your script from the folder where your file is stored? Have your tried print `os.getcwd()`to check the working directory ? The working directory is not the one in wich is your script but the one from where you launch it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file name is looked up in the current working directory, which is not necessarily the same as the directory the script lives in.  Try using the full path to the file, or make sure the working directory is correct.  You can check the working directory py printing `os.getcwd()` from inside your script (make sure you `import os`).

If you are on a case-sensitive file system, check the case of your file name.

Comment: what he means is say your running your script from home like this: `home/user/> python /programming/python/script.py` its thinking that the `dracula.txt` is in `/home/user/`

Comment: @JohnRiselvato ah ok I will try including the path to the file then. Thanks for the help both of you :)

Comment: Remember if this is the correct answer for you, click the check button.

Comment: It works! Thanks :D, although in retrospect I regret double checking by using print, the list is 50,000 words long haha.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato I shall do, however it's saying I have to wait for 3 minutes :(

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file is in the same directory as your .py file

```
import os

lines = open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'dracula.txt'), 'r').readlines()
```

Comment: How is this supposed to make a difference to the original code?

Comment: The joining with cwd is a NOP.

Comment: This is the default behavior he is already getting. `os.getcwd()` should be changed to the path to the desired file. Something like: `open(os.path.join('/path/to/vamipres', 'dracula.txt'), 'r').readlines()`